# osgi bundles version in felix after package uninstall in aem

Tags: aem

I have a doubt regarding osgi bundles version in felix console after uninstalling the package in aem. The build plan is that the packages are installed incremently with the build version like 1.13.1 then 1.13.2 and so on.

If there is a package `package-1.13.4.zip` installed; which has a bundle `bundle-1.13.4.jar`

After uninstalling the `package-1.13.4.zip`; as per my understanding; the `bundle-1.13.4.jar` should be removed from `apps/myproject/install` as well as from the felix console; the bundle that should be installed in felix console should be `bundle-1.13.3.jar`; since it was the version which was installed prior to 1.13.4

But when I uninstall `package-1.13.4.zip` ; neither the `bundle-1.13.4.jar` gets removed from `apps/myproject/install`  nor the `bundle-1.13.4.jar`  gets removed from the felix console. Is there something wrong with my understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of things which might be the issue  here :

1) check if your package has /apps/myproject/install in the filter list. Uninstalling your package package-1.13.4.zip will only remove your bundle bundle-1.13.4.jar, if the path /apps/myproject/install is in the filter list of your package.

2) Check your deployment scripts. There might be a case that your bundle is not installed using JCRInstaller. Your bundle will be uninstalled only if the bundle was installed using /apps/myproject/install. if your jenkins/maven script has installed your bundle directly using felix console or /system/console/ then uninstalling the pacakge will not uninstall the bundle.

If you want to make sure that when you uninstall the package then your bundle should also get uninstalled then do the following :

1) use Maven sling plugin - this will make sure that your bundle is installed at /apps//install.

2) Make sure your deployment scripts are installing the bundle at /apps//install and uploading to the felix console directly.

Comment: The bundles are installed using JCRInstaller in the maven script. The script uses the 'install' goal of sling plugin and provides the sling url as localhost:4502 and slingurlsuffix as /apps/myproject/install. In filter.xml; /apps/myproject/install has been excluded using <exclude pattern="/apps/myproject/install.*"/> . Is this the reason for bundles not getting uninstalled; what could be the reason for excluding the bundles? We would want the bundles to be removed from felix after a package is uninstalled right?

Answer (score 0):

> After uninstalling the package-1.13.4.zip; as per my understanding; the bundle-1.13.4.jar should be removed from apps/myproject/install as well as from the felix console; the bundle that should be installed in felix console should be bundle-1.13.3.jar; since it was the version which was installed prior to 1.13.4

Uninstalling the bundle does not restore its previous version in felix console and it maintains only one version of the bundle at any time. Also, build-installing the old version will not replace existing greater version installed. If the SNAPSHOT has been removed from the version name one cannot build-install it after uninstalling.